# Asp.Net Core 2.0 logging out after 30 seconds

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-2.0

I have an issue with production env (shared hosting): it keeps logging me out after 30 seconds, but on the development machine it works fine. I'm using identity `SignInManager`.

I've tried the following as suggested on github:

```
services.Configure<SecurityStampValidatorOptions>(options => options.ValidationInterval = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10));
services.AddAuthentication()
        .Services.ConfigureApplicationCookie(options =>
        {
            options.SlidingExpiration = true;
            options.ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(30);
        });
```

Comment: Have you specified the timeout may be in you config files.

Comment: @aman There are no "config files" in ASP.NET Core

Comment: Something this would help: https://github.com/aspnet/Identity/issues/1389

Comment: @aman That is where I've got the suggested code above, but it doesn't fix the problem

Comment: If you look at the cookie in the browser, what are you seeing for an expiration time? Also, does removing the validation affect this?

Comment: The expiration date is +14 days. Maybe there's a problem with my hosting provider, because like I've said, it works fine on my development machine.

Comment: I've spoke with the hosting provider. The application pool memory was very low.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently this was a memory issue. I've spoke with the hosting provider. The application pool memory was under 256MB.

Answer (score 0):

Inside your Startup.cs file add the following:

```
ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
//your code here
services.AddDataProtection()
.SetApplicationName("your-app-name")
.PersistKeysToFileSystem(new DirectoryInfo("your-path-here"));
//your code here
}
```

You can check the [details here.](http://blog.etrupja.com/2018/08/the-antiforgery-token-could-not-be-decrypted/)

Comment: This doesn't answer the question